# With PHP JpGraph PiePlotC (a donut) how can I set borders?

Tags: php, jpgraph

Ideally, I'd like to set slice borders but not circumference border.
I tried this:

```
$p1 = new PiePlotC($data);
$p1->ShowBorder(true);
$p1->SetColor('blue');
```

I also tried `$p1->ShowBorder(false, true);`
No border appeared.
I noticed that the theme: UniversalTheme set the border to false.
I remmed those lines out of the theme.

```
case 'PiePlot':
            {
                //$plot->SetCenter(0.5, 0.45);
                //$plot->ShowBorder(false);
                //$plot->SetSliceColors($this->GetThemeColors());
                break;
            }
```

That did not help.
The pie slice colors did appear even though I remmed that line out.
I know that theme is the one used because I had to rem:
`$plot->SetCenter(0.5, 0.45);` out to be able to move the pie.
That worked.

I think it's a bad design to have the theme overwrite settings set by the client (user).
The user's settings should override the theme.

**How can I set borders for each slice in a PiePlotC?

Also, how can I set the size (line width) of the borders?**

```
<?php 
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/Business/Config.php');
require_once (BASE_PATH . '/PHPJpGraph/jpgraph.php');
require_once (BASE_PATH . '/PHPJpGraph/jpgraph_pie.php');
 
$data = array(50,28,25,27,31,20);
 
// A new pie graph
$graph = new PieGraph(1000,1000,'auto');
$graph->SetFrame(false);
$graph->title->Set("PiePlotC");
$graph->title->SetFont(FF_ARIAL,FS_BOLD,18);
$graph->title->SetMargin(8); // Add a little bit more margin from the top

$p1 = new PiePlotC($data);
//$p1->clearTheme();
$p1->ShowBorder(true);
$p1->SetColor('blue');
//$p1->SetBorder($aWeight, $aColor);

$p1->SetLabelType(PIE_VALUE_ABS);
$p1->value->SetFormat("%d");
$p1->SetSize(0.35);
$p1->SetCenter(0.5, 0.5);
$p1->value->SetFont(FF_ARIAL,FS_BOLD,12);
$p1->value->Show(); 
$p1->SetMidSize(0.75);
$p1->midtitle->Set("Test mid\nRow 1\nRow 2");
$p1->midtitle->SetFont(FF_ARIAL,FS_NORMAL,12);

$p1->SetMidColor('white');
$p1->SetLabelType(PIE_VALUE_ABS);
$lbl = array("adam\n%.1f","bertil\n%.1f","johan\n%.1f",
         "peter\n%.1f","daniel\n%.1f","erik\n%.1f%%");
         
$p1->SetLabels($lbl);
$graph->Add($p1);
$graph->Stroke();
```

Answer (score 0):

Right after the new PieGraph clear the default theme using `$graph->clearTheme();` and see if that helps.

```
$graph = new PieGraph(1000,1000,'auto');
$graph->clearTheme();
```

I find nothing in the examples or documentation that indicates that the borders and size for pie slices may be changed. You may want to see if using ExplodeAll `$p1->ExplodeAll(5);` would help. There are also options to explode 1 or more slices but not all of them. And there are several themes provide as well as the option to set the colors of each slice yourself.

Comment: Thanks but what you suggesting doesn't work. 
$p1->clearTheme(); throws an  undefined method error as does $p1->SetBorder.
So far, ShowBorder and SetColor do nothing.
The version I'm using is JpGraph 4.4.1.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the complete code that fails along with enough data to reproduce the problem.

Comment: The editor will not let me save a url in the post.
the files are https : // dev.aecperformance.com/JpGraphTest.php, https : // dev.aecperformance.com/JpGraphTest.txt, https : // dev.aecperformance.com/JpGraphTestBad.php, https : // dev.aecperformance.com/JpGraphTestBad.txt

Comment: You just need to [edit] the question and add the code directly in a code section (I took care of that for you). That said the theme clear is associated with the PieGraph itself not the pie plot. Please see my modified answer.

Comment: I see, clearTheme is on the graph not the plot. I'm guessing that ShowBorder does nothing then? I'll look into ExplodeAll on Monday. Thanks.

Comment: According to the documentation the default is to show an outer circle and lines between each slice BUT, it only applies to PiePlot not PiePlotC.